# How do we resolve JUnit Mockito not being found in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, mockito

Here is my error message:
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type MockitoJUnitRunner not present
at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:46)
at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.value(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:513)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MockitoJUnitRunner
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:440)
at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:421)
at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:350)
at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:287)
at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:121)
at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:73)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3757)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3746)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3651)
at org.junit.internal.builders.IgnoredBuilder.runnerForClass(IgnoredBuilder.java:10)
... 12 more
mockitojunitrunner is not present error

Comment: You should format the stack trace as code to make it much more readable. In the stack trace, there is an error message: `ClassNotFoundException: MockitoJUnitRunner` Looks like this class is missing. Maybe you forgot to add a dependency to your build file. Please post your build file for more info and describe, what you already tried yourself to solve your problem.

Comment: @McPringle I tried to do that and it ended up like this.. will do that next time. Yea I thought the same thing that the dependency / class was missing. I will check my build file.